# Exponentiate rate matrix for continuous time Markov chain describing elementary transitions between subsets of {1, ..., n}.

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, matrix-exponential

My continuous time Markov chain describes transitions between subsets of ${\{1,\dots, n\}}$. Only elementary transitions are considered (+1 element, -1 element), and the empty subset is absorbing. The corresponding rates matrix $Q$ is of size $2^n$ because it is indexed by these subsets, but it can be described with only $n^2$ values:

- $n$ "loss" values quantifying the rates of transitions loosing 1 element: $(E_1,\dots,E_n)$
- $n^2-n$ "gain" values quantifying the rates of transitions gaining 1 element from another element already in the set: $(D_{12}, D_{13},\dots,D_{1n},D_{21}, D_{23},\dots,D_{2n},\dots)$

For instance with $n=3$, only the following values are required.. (real, positive or zero)

$\left[\begin{matrix}
E_1 & D_{12} & D_{13} \\
D_{21} & E_2 & D_{23} \\
D_{31} & D_{32} & E_3
\end{matrix}\right]$

.. to fully specify $Q$:

$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
  Q              & \varnothing & \{1\} & \{2\} & \{3\} & \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} & \{2,3\} & \{1,2,3\} \\\hline
  \varnothing           & \cdot & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0       & 0       & 0       & 0         \\
  \{1\}           & E_1   & \cdot & 0     & 0     & D_{12}  & D_{13}  & 0       & 0         \\
  \{2\}           & E_2   & 0     & \cdot & 0     & D_{21}  & 0       & D_{23}  & 0 \\
  \{3\}           & E_3   & 0     & 0     & \cdot & 0       & D_{31}  & D_{32}  & 0 \\
  \{1,2\}         & 0     & E_2   & E_1   & 0     & \cdot   & 0       & 0       & D_{13} + D_{23} \\
  \{1,3\}         & 0     & E_3   & 0     & E_1   & 0       & \cdot   & 0       & D_{12} + D_{32}\\
  \{2,3\}         & 0     & 0     & E_3   & E_2   & 0       & 0       & \cdot   & D_{21} + D_{31}\\
  \{1,2,3\}       & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & E_3     & E_2     & E_1     & \cdot\\
  \end{array}
$

(diagonal elements are set so that every row sums to zero)

More generally, for every positive integer $n$ and for every two distinct subsets of
$\{1,\dots,n\}$ $u$ and $v$ with $v$ non-empty, there is:

$\displaystyle\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\},\quad v = u \setminus \{i\} \implies Q_{uv} = E_i\quad$ (elementary loss)

$\displaystyle\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\},\quad v = u \cup \{i\} \implies Q_{uv} = \sum_{j\in u}{Dji}\quad$ (elementary gain)

$\displaystyle u = \varnothing \implies Q_{uv} = 0\quad$ (absorbing empty set)

$\displaystyle|v| \geqslant |u| + 2 \implies Q_{uv} = 0\quad$ (non-elementary gain)

$\displaystyle|v| \leqslant |u| - 2 \implies Q_{uv} = 0$ (non-elementary loss)

$\displaystyle Q_{uu} = -\sum_{v\neq u}{Q_{uv}}\quad$ (zero-sum rows)

Given that $Q$ is very sparse, very structured, and contains very few information with respect to its size, does it exhibit properties that would make

$e^{Qt}$

efficient to compute, for positive, real values of $t$?